# Some dynamic code is being attached on top of my code, how can solve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a working site, but since yesterday i am facing a problem that some dynamic javascript code is being attached on top of my html. which is giving error due to which some redirection code of javascript is not working. can anyone help please?

**CODE**

```
http://rjs.mzcdn.com/v3/loader.js?17000&amp;appid=53&amp;subid=@@@%20is%20giving%20error
```

Comment: If this code is not yours then your site might have been compromised.

Comment: no, custom html with php javascript and jquery

Comment: Nope your site is not compromised. Your browser is compromised. This is a malicious extension/plugin. Try to remove it from browser.

Comment: Thanks, you saved mylife, i was getting it since yesterday, and yes there was an extension added in chrome browser i disabled it and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got answer of this question and it is actually the comment of @Shudhansh Shekhar that is:

**Your browser is compromised. This is a malicious extension/plugin. Try to remove it from browser.**

Thanks buddy you solved my problem.